# IllegalStateException: drag shadow dimensions must be positive

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception, android-9.0-pie

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder#public-constructors

When I use the second constructor outlined above - 
"View.DragShadowBuilder()
Construct a shadow builder object with no associated View."

the following exception is raised: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Drag shadow dimensions must be positive

The second line of code here causes this for me:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    view.startDragAndDrop(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(), view, 0); 
    return true;
}
```

It occurs on Android 9 Pie only. I have tried it on previous Android versions with no problem. I created an issue on the Android issue tracker, but maybe someone here knows why it happens or how to resolve it.

In the meantime I am creating the new View.DragShadowBuilderView(view) with view being a transparent ImageView which stops the crash for now but I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need to create a transparent view. Create a custom `DragShadowBuilder`

```
public class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point outShadowSize, Point outShadowTouchPoint) {
        outShadowSize.set(1,1);
        outShadowTouchPoint.set(0,0);
    }
}
```

and replace `new View.DragShadowBuilder()` with `new MyDragShadowBuilder()`.

Comment: Thank you, this does work. For my project I didn't want a drag shadow, just the functionality, hence the empty constructor. The android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder.html#View.DragShadowBuilder()) now specify "This constructor variant is only useful when the onProvideShadowMetrics(Point, Point) and onDrawShadow(Canvas) methods are also overridden" like your answer suggests. In the end, I found an OnTouchListener was better for my purposes.

Comment: My app experiences the same crash but only manifests in the Play Store's PreLaunch report (Pixel 2, 9.0). Judging by the pre-launch video, it happens during the generic long-press text selection. I don't do anything in my app regarding drag and drop, other than allowing text selection in text views. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't even use `DragShadowBuilder` in my app. How come I got a crash of `Drag shadow dimensions must be positive` ? I saw it on Crashlytics...

Comment: @androiddeveloper It can happen somewhere inside some android widgets.  One suspect might be EditText - It supports drag and drop, and potentially can throw this exception.

Comment: @Sver What can I do about it, if it's about EditText? It does show this `TextView.performLongClick` , so maybe you are right...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I think it can be caused from `TextView` which is selectable, it has also this drag and drop when you select and long click text can drag

Comment: @Ultimo_m But what can I do about it? I don't even have DragShadowBuilder anywhere in code...

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't, but first make sure its not a library that you use doing drag&drop, try to update your dependencies, or try to log in crashlytics in which screen use has that crash and to locate the view and what user is doing that this issue occurs

Comment: @Ultimo_m I use normal EditText. Only Google might have changed it to the material version.

Comment: `outShadowSize` and` outShadowTouchPoint` where are defined On my custom Dragshadow builder the linter cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new class you can use [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
val shadowBuilder = object : View.DragShadowBuilder(view) {
        override fun onProvideShadowMetrics(outShadowSize: Point, outShadowTouchPoint: Point) {
            super.onProvideShadowMetrics(outShadowSize, outShadowTouchPoint)
            outShadowSize.set(width, height)
            outShadowTouchPoint.set(xPoint, yPoint)
        }
    }
```

You can put `xPoint` and `yPoint` as use touch point values:

```
    val xPoint = event.x
    val yPoint = event.y
```